# Failed Audit: where is the risk or spam in this question, its text or its comments itself?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, spam

After reviewing carefully the question text  and the visible comments.

I don't see clearly where is the risk or intention to spam.

It does not even include a link or the most minimum attempt that suggests download any risky content. Neither it is offering any particular promotion for something else.

In a given case, this particular situation, presented here, can even be considered an interesting use case, since any product can mark the result of your compilation `dll` or `exe` as a Trojan, because of whatever mechanism is used to determinate it. Or simply because of any other combination of factors (file name, path, combination of instructions).

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/16489816
[image: Review Audit Failed]

**Edited:**

Here you have an simple comparative analysis 4 similar questions, so if the previous one is unsalvageable and widely off-topic, then these should be evaluated.

As expressed by moderators and down voters "You should have flagged the question for closure accordingly".

Questions 3 and 4 are really elaborate, while 1 and 2 are pretty similar in length and approach.

1. [My C# program is detected as a virus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960407/my-c-sharp-program-is-detected-as-a-virus)
2. [Fix anti-virus detection of my software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534050/fix-anti-virus-detection-of-my-software)
3. [My programs are blocked by avast anti-virus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375340/my-programs-are-blocked-by-avast-anti-virus)
4. [C# Application being blocked by Anti-Virus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888301/c-sharp-application-being-blocked-by-anti-virus)

[image: Analysis of similar questions]

Comment: You should link to the actual review, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: So what is the solution here, let the OP email you the possibly infected file so you can test it on your machine? And even so, what's the added value for the rest of the community? This will never help anyone but the OP

Comment: The question itself is widely off-topic, no amount of editing will make it on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @servy Since it's a already deleted question, it's not available anymore, it is why the screenshot.

Comment: @EmersonCastaneda I'm well aware that it's deleted, and yet there's all sorts of information I can't see about the post and your review of it in your screenshot, that I would be able to see if I went to the question.  Deleted posts still exist; they're simply hidden.

Comment: The review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/16489816, for the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44125044/hello-world-trojan-flag

Comment: I would vote to close for not having enough information to debug.

Comment: The "requires editing" response *sounds* like it is correct (the post should be edited to be a good question), but that response is actually *people **other than the asker** can edit this question and make it a good question* which is not the case here (**only** the asker can fix it in this case). There've been numerous posts on meta about that wording being poor and you sorta got bit by it.

Answer (score 13):

> I don't see clearly where is the risk or intention to spam.

Neither do I.  Of course, just because the post isn't spam doesn't mean that the post is acceptable, or that the post can be made to be acceptable through community editing.

The post, as it sits, is simply unsalvageable, not because it's spam, but because it's way too broad, and completely lacking in sufficient information to provide an answer.   You should have flagged the question for closure accordingly.

Comment: The first revision at least had a link but that was edited out. Not saying that the link was spam ...

Answer (score 12):

The question had a spam flag on it at the time that I deleted it, which is why it ended up as an audit. The "possible spam" warning can be caused by a number of factors, including heuristics that throw false positives, so I would only use that as a notice that this is a post that might require closer review.

As for why I didn't decline or clear the spam flag before I deleted that post, this is how it looked before someone edited it:

[image: Problematic question]

They're asking the community to download a random file from a download site that may or may not be infected with a virus. That looked super sketchy to me (we've seen people try to spread trojans via questions like this), so I validated the spam flag and deleted the post.

As others have indicated, I wasn't worried about this appearing as an audit, because it was an unsalvageable question. There's no way the community could edit that into shape, so choosing "looks OK" or "requires editing" are proper failure states for this audit.

Comment: I think you are making the point. "this is how it looked". So, for sure "choosing "looks OK" or "requires editing" are proper failure states for this audit" if the link were still there when I made the review, but it was not the case for me. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @EmersonCastaneda - Even without the link, that question is unsalvageable. There's nothing the community could edit to make it acceptable, so "requires editing" is an incorrect choice in its current state.